# Installed MySQL but can't find it

Tags: linux, mysql

I've just finished installing mysql and mysqlserver on centOS as part of a larger install script (the full script is [here](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/setup-web2py-fedora.sh), though I uncommented the mysql part).

The script ran fine, and it even walked me through the paces of setting up the mysql root password etc.

Script output:

> Installed:
>   mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1
>   mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.1.61-1.el6_2.1

Now, in the same session is SSH, I'm unable to access mysql or find any reference to it.

> $ mysql -u root -p
>   -bash: mysql: command not found
>
> $ which mysql
>   /usr/bin/which: no mysql in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

It's just weird- where is it??

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your script and SSH session are on the same machine?  What happens if you run "rpm -ql mysql" to list the files installed by the mysql package?

Answer (score 3):

`which` is only aware of what's in your path.

Either chances are this installed somewhere like `/opt/mysql/bin` or elsewhere.

I'd suggest running `updatedb && locate bin/mysql` to get a more vast coverage of where it could be.

Also, you should confirm it's actually running `ps waux |grep mysql` - that should also give you where the binaries are if it installed and launched the daemon.

Comment: Red Hat, Fedora and CentOS packages install the mysql client to /usr/bin usually.  Unless the script (I can't download it to check for myself) sets up some external repositories I'd expect these packages to install to /usr/bin.

Comment: One would expect ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mysql
```

or

```
mysql --version
```

Try looking in /var/lib/mysql/. Thats where it is usually stored. If not then your installation failed, and like the above answer check if the installation part is commented out or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your script didn't install. The installation part is commented

# MySQL install untested!
  # Install mysql packages (optional)
  #yum install mysql mysql-server

# Enable mysql to start at boot (optional)
  #chkconfig --levels 235 mysqld on
  #service mysqld start

Comment: According to the question the OP uncommented that part.  But it is something to check to be certain.  What is the output of `rpm -qa|grep mysql`?

Comment: Bram thank you. Sorry I misread the question. Yes your suggestion is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

find / -name mysql

Or alternatively try rehash(1) to rebuild the path cache, then try to login to MySQL again.

Don't forget to start the server too